# The task that is written in the microdef is terminating after the the microdef block executed

Tags: xml, azure-devops, ant, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am starting windchill through command prompt. So, for that using ant 'macrodef' task,I have written the buildscript for that, but after running that build script, I am able to start windchill but after executing 'macrodef' block Windchill stop automatically.How to do I overcome this issue?

```
   <macrodef name="start.wdc" description="Start Windchill">
       <sequential>
           <echo message="Starting Windchill: ${wc_cmd} start"/> 
           <exec executable="${wc_cmd}">  
               <arg value="start"/>  
           </exec>
           <sleep seconds="200"/>   
       </sequential>
   </macrodef>                  

   <target name= "start">
       <start.wdc/>      
   </target>
```